# Futures-Util version issue

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, rust-futures

My code was working fine until today I got the error

```
error: the 'rustc.exe' binary, normally provided by the 'rustc' component, is not applicable to the 'stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc' toolchain
```

I fixed it with `rustup toolchain install stable`

After that I am having dependency issue with futures-util.

My toml file is:

```
[package]
name = "rusting"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

    # See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html
    
    [dependencies]
    rand = "0.8.5"
    
    schnorr_fun = "0.8.2"
    
    chrono = "0.4.24"
    
    tokio = { version = "1.27.0", features = ["full"] }
    
    futures = "0.3.28"
    
    schnorrkel = "0.10.2"
    
    serde_json = "1.0.95"
```

I am getting error (after running cargo run):

```
  Compiling autocfg v1.1.0
   Compiling proc-macro2 v1.0.56
   Compiling cfg-if v1.0.0
   Compiling unicode-ident v1.0.8
   Compiling quote v1.0.26
   Compiling version_check v0.9.4
   Compiling typenum v1.16.0
   Compiling windows_x86_64_msvc v0.42.2
   Compiling getrandom v0.2.9
   Compiling winapi v0.3.9
   Compiling rand_core v0.6.4
   Compiling generic-array v0.14.7
   Compiling futures-core v0.3.28
   Compiling slab v0.4.8
   Compiling windows-targets v0.42.2
   Compiling futures-task v0.3.28                                                                                                                                               
   Compiling futures-channel v0.3.28
   Compiling serde v1.0.160
   Compiling memchr v2.5.0                                                                                                                                                      
   Compiling windows-sys v0.45.0                                                                                                                                                
   Compiling lock_api v0.4.9
   Compiling num-traits v0.2.15
   Compiling syn v2.0.15
   Compiling futures-util v0.3.28
   Compiling libc v0.2.142
   Compiling subtle-ng v2.5.0
   Compiling log v0.4.17
   Compiling futures-sink v0.3.28
   Compiling parking_lot_core v0.9.7
   Compiling pin-project-lite v0.2.9
   Compiling num-integer v0.1.45
   Compiling pin-utils v0.1.0
   Compiling byteorder v1.4.3
   Compiling futures-io v0.3.28
   Compiling crypto-common v0.1.6
   Compiling digest v0.9.0
   Compiling scopeguard v1.1.0
   Compiling smallvec v1.10.0
   Compiling digest v0.10.6
   Compiling block-buffer v0.9.0
   Compiling tokio v1.27.0
   Compiling ppv-lite86 v0.2.17
   Compiling cpufeatures v0.2.7
   Compiling opaque-debug v0.3.0
   Compiling keccak v0.1.3
   Compiling serde_json v1.0.96
   Compiling sha2 v0.9.9
   Compiling rand_chacha v0.3.1
   Compiling mio v0.8.6
   Compiling parking_lot v0.12.1
   Compiling time v0.1.45
   Compiling socket2 v0.4.9
   Compiling secp256kfun v0.8.2
   Compiling itoa v1.0.6
   Compiling bytes v1.4.0
   Compiling arrayvec v0.7.2
   Compiling arrayref v0.3.7
   Compiling ryu v1.0.13
   Compiling num_cpus v1.15.0
   Compiling chrono v0.4.24
   Compiling rand v0.8.5
   Compiling schnorr_fun v0.8.2
   Compiling serde_bytes v0.11.9
   Compiling zeroize_derive v1.4.2
   Compiling futures-macro v0.3.28
   Compiling tokio-macros v2.0.0
   Compiling zeroize v1.6.0
   Compiling curve25519-dalek-ng v4.1.1
   Compiling merlin v3.0.0
   Compiling schnorrkel v0.10.2
error: could not compile `futures-util`

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `rustc --crate-name futures_util --edition=2018 C:\Users\write\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\futures-util-0.3.28\src\lib.rs --error-format=json --json=diagnostic-rendered-ansi,artifacts,future-incompat --diagnostic-width=175 --crate-type lib --emit=dep-info,metadata,link -C embed-bitcode=no -C debuginfo=2 --cfg "feature=\"alloc\"" --cfg "feature=\"async-await\"" --cfg "feature=\"async-await-macro\"" --cfg "feature=\"channel\"" --cfg "feature=\"futures-channel\"" --cfg "feature=\"futures-io\"" --cfg "feature=\"futures-macro\"" --cfg "feature=\"futures-sink\"" --cfg "feature=\"io\"" --cfg "feature=\"memchr\"" --cfg "feature=\"sink\"" --cfg "feature=\"slab\"" --cfg "feature=\"std\"" -C metadata=13742af156b34500 -C extra-filename=-13742af156b34500 --out-dir C:\Users\write\OneDrive\Desktop\rustMainWorks\rusting\target\debug\deps -L dependency=C:\Users\write\OneDrive\Desktop\rustMainWorks\rusting\target\debug\deps --extern futures_channel=C:\Users\write\OneDrive\Desktop\rustMainWorks\rusting\target\debug\deps\libfutures_channel-3e8bb2b5c1dc081e.rmeta --extern futures_core=C:\Users\write\OneDrive\Desktop\rustMainWorks\rusting\target\debug\deps\libfutures_core-f90c1bbd638684b0.rmeta --extern futures_io=C:\Users\write\OneDrive\Desktop\rustMainWorks\rusting\target\debug\deps\libfutures_io-71770888c0d02b09.rmeta --extern futures_macro=C:\Users\write\OneDrive\Desktop\rustMainWorks\rusting\target\debug\deps\futures_macro-2cc5ad0e7c87dece.dll --extern futures_sink=C:\Users\write\OneDrive\Desktop\rustMainWorks\rusting\target\debug\deps\libfutures_sink-c2d4171c0b21bc55.rmeta --extern futures_task=C:\Users\write\OneDrive\Desktop\rustMainWorks\rusting\target\debug\deps\libfutures_task-ed665921dfd5aad9.rmeta --extern memchr=C:\Users\write\OneDrive\Desktop\rustMainWorks\rusting\target\debug\deps\libmemchr-0d3a18afe7a073e7.rmeta --extern pin_project_lite=C:\Users\write\OneDrive\Desktop\rustMainWorks\rusting\target\debug\deps\libpin_project_lite-ae131f81c3df234f.rmeta --extern pin_utils=C:\Users\write\OneDrive\Desktop\rustMainWorks\rusting\target\debug\deps\libpin_utils-55686e91c4a501a2.rmeta --extern slab=C:\Users\write\OneDrive\Desktop\rustMainWorks\rusting\target\debug\deps\libslab-c0d5a42b8ab0b0ff.rmeta --cap-lints allow` (exit code: 1263094860)
```

I can understand there's some dependancy clash. But I cant fix it.
Maybe tokio also is using a future crate with a different dependency.
Any help please.

Comment: Try running `cargo clean`

Comment: I did it actually.

Comment: Cargo clean followed by cargo update

Comment: @Zubayr and I'm guessing that worked?

Comment: @PeterHall yes. Along with restarting the vs code.

Comment: @Zubayr Request you to update the question with the solution, so that it becomes clear that it has been resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution by myself.

First just try

```
cargo clean
```

followed by

```
cargo update
```

Then try `cargo run`

If it doesn't work, just restart your ide (for me vs code) and try `cargo clean` again.